regex to match HTML <p ...> tag starting with a lowercase letter
I am editing an epub file in
Sigil and would like to match
HTML <p ...> tags when the 1st char after the closing tag > is
in lower case. I saw some answers on this site to match p tags
with attributes, but not a p tag without attributes. I don't know
how regular expressions work, so I'm trying to figure out what
change I need to do to match both?
Examples:
<p class="calibre1">All the while I was...</p>
<p>All the while I was...</p>
<p class="calibre1">all the while I was...</p>
<p>all the while I was...</p>

The regex should match the last 2 tags in the example above.
The code that I have (/<\/?([^p](\s.+?)?|..+?)>[a-z]/) matches
only the 3rd, not the 4th tag.
Important: Sigil has no HTML parser, so I have to stick to using
the simple search engine which accepts regular expressions.

Don't use regular expressions to process HTML, use an HTML parser.

It's a Thing That Should Not Be.

Don't try to run a regex directly on the HTML, but use the DOM to first get the paragraphs with document.querySelectorAll('p'). Then on each of them, look at the innerText property and test it against /^\p{Ll}/u, to see if it starts with a lowercase letter in any language (using the Unicode flag). The reasons are multiple: A. HTML entities: &eacute; is é and is a lowercase letter. B. Your paragraph could start with an inner tag like <p><strong>shit</strong> starts with a lowercase...</p>. C. Spaces, tabs, new lines, HTML comments before the first letter.

sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm editing an epub file using Sigil, which has only regex and no HTML parser.

In Sigil search for <p([^>]*)>((?:\s*|<!--.*?-->|<\s*\w+[^>]*>)*)(\p{Ll}) with the regex options "Dot All" and "Unicode Property" and replace by <p\1>\2\U\3\E to directly convert the lowercase letter to its uppercase version. \U will uppercase the capturing group n°3, which is the lowercase letter. \E stops the uppercase modifier.

The following regex looks like a good starting place:

<p[^>]*?>[a-z]


From there I'm not sure what you want to capture, but it'll work. And yes, of course you should you an HTMLParser for this, but for something as simple as this I don't see why regex is an issue (provided you know the input, it won't work on a generalized html input).

@Kosh I understood it the same way as David542. But unfortunately, like I commented on the original question, [a-z] will not match lowercase letters with accents or in other languages. And furthermore, it will not work if we have spaces, tabs, new lines, HTML comments in front of the letter, neither work with HTML entities like &agrave; = à or with inner HTML tags, like <p><strong>lowercase</strong>...</p>.

@PatrickJanser, yes, you right. That was me who misunderstood the question. Looks like I need more expensive glasses =))

@Kosh Ahahah! Well, to be honest I had to read it 3 times.

@PatrickJanser, thanks for this tip, if I want to include lower case with accents or in other languages, what should I use instead of [a-z]?

That's going to break on any paragraph which uses > in an attribute value. Regex are not suitable for parsing HTML with.

@Michael : As mentioned in my comment on your question, you have to use \p{Ll} to match a lowercase letter, using the unicode regex flag. You'll find more details here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

For @Michael, if you need to match a few of the cases I mentioned, you can have a go with this regular expression and example: https://regex101.com/r/p6lO1Y/1 In Sigil, you can't use commented regex, but you can do the search with <p[^>]*>(?:\s*|<!--.*?-->|<\s*\w+[^>]*>)*(\p{Ll}) if you activate the regex options Dot All and Unicode Property.

@Quentin Yes, in some bad situations, you could have < or > in a tag attribute, but normally, in correctly formed HTML, attribute values should be escaped (ex: <img src="right-arrow.png" alt="-&gt;" title="Right arrow" ... />). As Sigil doesn't offer a parser but just a search engine, we can only try to solve it with a regex, which, effectively, will never cover all the cases :-/

@PatrickJanser — No. You can represent < and > as entities in an attribute value but there is no requirement to do so, even if it would have special meaning in other contexts. It is wrong to say they should be expressed as &lt; / &gt;

@Quentin Thanks for the information. I just thought that the case would be rather rare for his use case of looking into his epub content (probably generated by a tool which would create modern HTML, which would be escaped). And as he can only use a regex in Sigil (and will probably not program a script with a proper parser), he could still handle this case with a bit more logic in the regex: https://regex101.com/r/p6lO1Y/4

@PatrickJanser nice work that looks very clean.
